# How to Remove/Edit MAGENTO Footer Credit

Tags: html, css, magento

I want to Remove the Credit From magento. i have tried many ways, but couldn't find the solution. 
by default it is
Magento Templates © 2015 [OnTheWay](http://www.ontheway247.com/). All Rights Reserved.
i want it to be like this 
© 2015 OnTheWay. All Rights Reserved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this css

`address.copyright > a {
    display: none;
}`

Comment: where to add it ? style.css ?

Comment: yes you need to include in css file which is running in your site